# PHP configuration: are max_execution_time and max_input_time values measured in seconds?

Tags: php

I'm checking my PHP configuration and I read

```
max_execution_time 30
max_input_time 60
```

Are these seconds or minutes ?

If they are seconds and, let's say, I need to upload a file of 20MB with a php script (CMS).. it is usually not enough, right ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's right. You'd better to use FTP for uploading such big files.
Your host might limit your upload size too (post_max_size).

`max_execution_time` does not include the time used for an upload. Please read this [manual page on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

Comment: post_max_size is 100MB. (1) so is only max_input_time the parameter I should change ? (2) is upload_max_filesize also important (as post_max_size) ? thanks

Comment: You should change [`max_input_time`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time), [`upload_max_filesize`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize), [`post_max_size`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), [`memory_limit`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).